# Spark-Core:port opened by the SparkDriver is vulnerable to flooding attacks

Tags: apache-spark

SparkSubmit will open the port to communicate with the APP Master and executors.

This port is not closing the IDLE connections,so it is vulnerable for DOS attack,I did telnet IP port and this connection is not closed.

In order to fix this I tried to Handle in the userEventTriggered of TransportChannelHandler.java  class,to my surprise APP master is also IDLE ,so fixing this will result in terminating the connection for APP master also.

Any one have you come across this type of problem,and is there any other way to fix this issue

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'd say that having your cluster accessible from the public network would be __completely insane__ anyway, but if you're concerned it would make more sense to bring this up on the [developers list](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/).